# Question about the proof $X'$ reflexive $\Rightarrow X$ reflexive.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, proof-explanation

I have a doubt in the proof I have been given of the fact:

For a Banach space $X$, if $X'$ is reflexive then $X$ is reflexive. This is proven by showing first **theorem 1** and **theorem 2**, which I quote here:

> **Theorem 1**: If a Banach space $X$ is reflexive then its dual space $X'$ is reflexive.
>
> **Theorem 2**: A closed subspace of a reflexive Banach space is reflexive.

**Proof**:

> *Proof*: Suppose $X'$ is reflexive. By Theorem 1 it follows that $X''$ is reflexive. If we consider the Canonical mapping $J : X \to X''$ it follows that $J(X)$ is a subspace of $X''$. Since $X \cong J(X)$ and $X$ is a Banach space, then $J(X)$ is a Banach space and hence closed. By Theorem 2 we can conclude that $J(X)$ is reflexive. But since $X \cong J(X)$ conclude that $X$ is reflexive.

The question is, Why is $J(X) \cong X$ ?, that is preciselly what I want to show, but I haven't been able to conclude it...

Comment: No, that is not precisely what you want to show.  $J(X)\cong X$ for all normed spaces $X$, even nonreflexive spaces (and even non-Banach spaces!).  Instead, you want to show that $X$ is reflexive.  You can do this by showing it is isomorphic to a closed subspace of a reflexive space (and then apply Theorem 2).  Note that the canonical embedding $J:X\to X''$ (defined by $(Jx)(x^*)=x^*(x)$ for all $x\in X$ and $x^*\in X'$) is indeed an embedding, i.e. is bounded below. The range of a bounded below (continuous linear) operator is always isomorphic to its domain. Hence $JX\cong X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, $\cong$ is to be interpreted as “isometrically isomorphic.” This means that there exists a map $f:X\to J(X)$ such that

- $f$ is linear;
- $f$ is bijective; and
- $f$ preserves norms: $\|f(x)\|_{J(x)}=\|x\|_X$ for each $x\in X$.

The natural candidate for such a function $f$ is the canonical mapping $J:X\to J(X)$ itself. By construction, it is surjective. It is not difficult to check that it is linear. In addition, one can use the Hahn–Banach theorem to establish that it preserves norms. This latter property actually implies also that $J$ is injective.

Comment: Sorry, now I get it, what we want to show is that $J(X)=X''$.